# PHP script keeps running indefinetly

Tags: php, glob

I have added following code to show files inside a directory

```
$exclude = array("index.php","cssheadertop.php","cssheaderbottom.php");
$cssfiles = array_diff(glob("*.php"), $exclude); 
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
    $filename = "http://8mags.com/lessons/css/".$cssfiles[$i];
    outputtags($filename,true,true); 
}
```

I don't know why but it keeps running indefinitely. the function `outputtags` is not problematic as the code below works fine

```
$exclude = array("index.php","cssheadertop.php","cssheaderbottom.php");
$cssfiles = array_diff(glob("*.php"), $exclude); 
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
    $cssfile = array_rand($cssfiles);
    $filename = "http://8mags.com/lessons/css/".$cssfiles[$cssfile];
    outputtags($filename,true,true); 
}
```

works perfectly.

Here is code for outputtags

```
function outputtags($filename,$other,$programming)
{
$html = file_get_contents_curl($filename);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
$meta = $metas->item($i);
if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:title')
    $ogtitle = $meta->getAttribute('content');
if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:image')
    $ogimage = $meta->getAttribute('content');
if($other)
{if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:description')
    $ogdescription = $meta->getAttribute('content');}
}
echo '<p style="margin:0;"><a href='.$filename.' target=_blank>'.$ogtitle.'</a></p>';
if(!$other)
echo '<a href='.$filename.' target=_blank><img style="margin:0 0 40px 0;" src="'.$ogimage.'" alt=""></a></br>';
if($other)
{
if(!$programming)
echo '<a href='.$filename.' target=_blank><img src="'.$ogimage.'" alt=""></a></br>';
echo '<p style="margin:0 0 40px 0;">'.$ogdescription.'</p>';
}
}
```

Edit after writing `exit;` in the end as suggested in comments I got

```
array(8) { [0]=> string(12) "3dbutton.php" [1]=> string(15) "basicbutton.php" [2]=> string(19) "basictextshadow.php" [5]=> string(11) "cssmenu.php" [6]=> string(21) "csstexteffectlogo.php" [7]=> string(22) "glossyroundbuttons.php" [8]=> string(18) "glowtextshadow.php" [10]=> string(26) "transitionhoverbuttons.php" }
```

Finally after using foreach script still keeps running for a long time any suggestions

```
foreach ($cssfiles as $cssfile) {
$filename = "http://8mags.com/lessons/css/".$cssfiles[$cssfile];
outputtags($filename,true,true); 
}
```

Comment: It has to be `outputtags()` nothing else can cause a infinite loop here. BTW: Why do you only iterate trough the first 5 files? Add error reporting and tell us the erorrs: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` Also show us your full script

Comment: At least post `outputtags()` also as Rizier123 says it may be causing the loop or affecting the loop you have it in.

Comment: Hey, I have edited to code, the problem is because of variable $i, I have changed nothing besides the variable I but the first snippet runs indefinitely

Comment: And if you comment out the `outputtags` line, does it still run infinately?

Comment: Have you declared $i global anywhere? Maybe outputtags is resetting it

Comment: use var_dump($cssfiles) to have a look at what is in the array. It appears there is an issue with the 0-5 numbering, whereas when you allow it to be random it keeps failing until it randomly lands on the correct key, allowing the script to eventually finish.

Comment: It stops crashing after I comment out `outputtags()` outputtags is a little big So,  I thought about not posting here. I will post it now.

Comment: Please show the results of the var_dump($cssfiles). The target=_blank is not in quotes target="_blank". View page source to see where the script stops.

Comment: Where do I have to write var_dump($cssfiles)

Comment: The loading circle just keeps revolving, Page source displays nothing.

Comment: In that case put an `exit`; at the end of `output_tags()`. If it's still in an infinite loop, move the `exit` up a bit until it does actually finish and you will see your output.

Comment: BTW is it possible that the problem is with getting `http://8mags.com/lessons/css/whatever`? Could it be stuck there? Your use of `$cssfiles` is different in the second piece of code - there it's an element of the array (`$cssfile`) whereas in the first piece it's and index (`$i`)

Comment: var_dump($cssfiles) right after you declare $cssfiles, before the for loop. If need be, temporarily remark out the for loop to get the results.

Comment: @colmde I have put the code that appears after I `exit;`

Comment: Your array keys are 0,1,2,5,6,7,etc... That's why it breaks when not using random, because it is looking for keys 3 and 4. You need to re key your array or use "for each" instead of iterating through the keys numerically.

Comment: I wonder if one of the PHP scripts you are trying to get is what contains the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array keys are 0,1,2,5,6,7,etc... That's why it breaks when not using random, because it is looking for keys 3 and 4. You need to re key your array or use "for each" instead of iterating through the keys numerically.

```
$exclude = array("index.php","cssheadertop.php","cssheaderbottom.php");
$cssfiles = array_diff(glob("*.php"), $exclude); 
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
    $filename = "http://8mags.com/lessons/css/".$cssfiles[$i];
    outputtags($filename,true,true); 
}
```

When running the script,

```
$filename = "http://8mags.com/lessons/css/".$cssfiles[3];
$filename = "http://8mags.com/lessons/css/".$cssfiles[4];
```

do not exist, so it breaks.

You're sending `http://8mags.com/lessons/css/` to your outputtags().